# getInputStream() Source code

Tags: java, abstract-class, inputstream

To get `InputStream` from `HttpURLConnection` we code like that

```
urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

If `InputStream` is an **Abstract** class then how `getInputStream()` method create a `InputStream` and return it as **Abstract** class can't be instantiated.

> Is the return type  is actually `InputStream` or subclass of
>   `InputStream` ?
>
> If it is actually  `InputStream` then how it's instantiated?

I want to look at the source code of this method so that i can understand how `InputStream` is instantiated and its actual type.
I searched in web but can't find any implemented code for `getInputStream()` method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Abstract classes are very similar to interfaces:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the return type is actually InputStream or subclass of 
>   InputStream?

Yes, abstract classes can't be instantiated and the returned object will be the type of the subclass of `InputStream`, you can find the subclasses of the `InputStream` from the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

Comment: Thanks. Where i will find getInputStream() method imlementation?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.getInputStream%28%29

Comment: Thanks for response :)